# Redirect all requests with parameter to URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect in .htaccess all requests that have `?setlang=it` at the end to `/it/` (italian homepage of the site).

What I tried was:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} setlang=it
RewriteRule ^(.*) /it/ [L,R=301]
```

But if i go to `/page/?setlang=it` it takes me to home on default language instead of `/it/`

My full htaccess code is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} setlang=de
RewriteRule ^(.*) / [L,R=301,QSD]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} setlang=fr
RewriteRule ^(.*) /fr/ [L,R=301,QSD]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} setlang=it
RewriteRule ^(.*) /it/ [L,R=301,QSD]
```

Comment: Add `QSD` flag to make it `[L,R=301,QSD]`

Comment: @anubhava I tried that and instead of redirecting to /it/ just adds ?setlang=it at the end of url

Comment: @anubhava updated the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^setlang=de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^setlang=(fr|it)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Placing redirect rules before catch-all WP rules and combining `fr` and `it` rules into one. Make sure to test this in a a new browser to avoid old browser cache.